# Select data and date range window in mysql with every 7 day interval from now

Tags: mysql

I have a table called symposium table, which is like this.

```
|----------------------------------------------------------------|
|      id      |   symposium_date  |   topic     |    price      |
|----------------------------------------------------------------|
|       1      |    2019-09-10     |   Piano     |   30.00       |
|       2      |    2019-09-09     |   Flute     |   20.00       |
|       3      |    2019-09-02     |   Piano     |   30.00       |
|       4      |    2019-08-26     |   Flute     |   20.00       |
|       5      |    2019-08-27     |   Flute     |   20.00       |
-----------------------------------------------------------------|
```

Say when I am running a query, the NOW() returns me the current datetime ie. 2019-09-13 05:21:50.

I want a query which will return me the start and end date of each seven day interval tracing backward from NOW(), within which each record falls. For better understanding, check this return set I want

```
|----------------------------------------------------------------|
| id  |   symposium_date  |   from-interval |    to-interval     |
|----------------------------------------------------------------|
| 1   |    2019-09-10     |   2019-09-07    |   2019-09-13       |
| 2   |    2019-09-09     |   2019-09-07    |   2019-09-13       |
| 3   |    2019-09-02     |   2019-08-31    |   2019-09-06       |
| 4   |    2019-08-26     |   2019-08-24    |   2019-09-30       |
| 5   |    2019-08-27     |   2019-08-24    |   2019-09-30       |
| ---------------------------------------------------------------|
```

How can I achieve this?

My current query is like his:-

```
SELECT id, symposium_date from FROM symposia 
WHERE (
         symposium_date >= ( NOW() + INTERVAL -7 DAY ) 
           AND symposium_date <= NOW() 
      ) 
      OR  symposium_date < (NOW() + INTERVAL -7 DAY)
```

But how can I fetch the interval range?

Comment: How are you defining a week?  Note that there are many ways to count weeks in a given year.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, this is not about pertaining any week, but any number of day range say like 10 days, or even 13 days.

Comment: @madhurbhaiya no, it doesn't, because the op is only interested in the week range of rows that actually exist

Comment: I've tested with `FROM_DAYS`, `TO_DAYS` & `DAYOFWEEK` functions in MySQL and its able to generate your example output but I see your comment about day range _"like 10 days, or even 13 days"_ and I'm not sure how do you mean by that. Can you show us how a 10 days or 13 days example output look like?

Answer (score 2):

**Note:** Following approach is suitable when there is a need of all the intervals. Eg: You need to get all the week range, irrespective of a `symposium_date` existing in the range or not. If you don't need all the intervals, then use this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57929123/2469308

---

Now, you require dynamic "start date" and "end date" for a "week" (7 day interval), depending on the non-deterministic `NOW()` function.

One way can be to utilize a [**number generator**](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmysql%5D%20number%20generator%20user%3A2469308) table here. You can either define a permanent table in your database storing integers ranging from 0 to 1000 (let's say). Or, you can use a [Derived Table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/derived-tables.html) (materialize a table for this query). For brevity, I am considering upto 3 intervals; however, you can also increase the numbers in the below query:

```
(SELECT 0 AS digit UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2) AS ngen
```

Now, we can create 7-day intervals starting from `CURRENT_DATE()` using some mathematics:

```
SELECT CURRENT_DATE() - INTERVAL (((ngen.digit+1)*7)-1) day AS from_interval,
       CURRENT_DATE() - INTERVAL ((ngen.digit)*7) day       AS to_interval
FROM   (SELECT 0 AS digit
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 1
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 2) ngen;

| from_interval | to_interval |
| ------------- | ----------- |
| 2019-09-07    | 2019-09-13  |
| 2019-08-31    | 2019-09-06  |
| 2019-08-24    | 2019-08-30  |
```

Now, we can simply use the above result-set as a [Derived Table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/derived-tables.html) and `JOIN` back to `symposia` table matching the `symposium_date` lying [`BETWEEN`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between) the specific pair of `from_interval` and `to_interval`:

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
CREATE TABLE symposia
    (`id` int, `symposium_date` date, `topic` varchar(5), `price` decimal(11,2))
;

INSERT INTO symposia
    (`id`, `symposium_date`, `topic`, `price`)
VALUES
    (1, '2019-09-10', 'Piano', 30.00),
    (2, '2019-09-09', 'Flute', 20.00),
    (3, '2019-09-02', 'Piano', 30.00),
    (4, '2019-08-26', 'Flute', 20.00),
    (5, '2019-08-27', 'Flute', 20.00)
;
```

---

**Query**

```
SELECT s.id,
       s.symposium_date,
       weeks.from_interval,
       weeks.to_interval
FROM   symposia s
       JOIN (SELECT CURRENT_DATE() - INTERVAL (((ngen.digit+1)*7)-1) day AS
                    from_interval,
                    CURRENT_DATE() - INTERVAL ((ngen.digit)*7) day       AS
                    to_interval
             FROM   (SELECT 0 AS digit
                     UNION ALL
                     SELECT 1
                     UNION ALL
                     SELECT 2) ngen) AS weeks
         ON s.symposium_date BETWEEN weeks.from_interval AND weeks.to_interval;
```

**Result**

```
| id  | symposium_date | from_interval | to_interval |
| --- | -------------- | ------------- | ----------- |
| 1   | 2019-09-10     | 2019-09-07    | 2019-09-13  |
| 2   | 2019-09-09     | 2019-09-07    | 2019-09-13  |
| 3   | 2019-09-02     | 2019-08-31    | 2019-09-06  |
| 4   | 2019-08-26     | 2019-08-24    | 2019-08-30  |
| 5   | 2019-08-27     | 2019-08-24    | 2019-08-30  |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fBR2jcGK6SS1gNR1zhg1h7/0)

Comment: This isn't necessary. Today is Friday, so the OP simply wants to know the nearest Friday on or after a given date.

Comment: @Strawberry please check the expected output in the problem statement. Also "*I want a query which will return me the start and end date of **each** seven day interval **tracing backward from NOW()**, within which each record falls.*" `NOW()` would be dynamic depending on the day the query is run, so the intervals will be dynamic.

Comment: I added a supplementary answer, by way of explanation.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATED: If Week range is dynamic based on a date:**

Day of given date would be considered as `last day` of week in this.

```
SET @c_date:= '2019-09-13';

SELECT 
    s.id,
   s.symposium_date,
   @st_date:= s.symposium_date + INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(@c_date) - DAYOFWEEK(s.symposium_date) + 1 - IF(DAYOFWEEK(@c_date) >= DAYOFWEEK(s.symposium_date), 7 , 0) DAY from_interval,
    @st_date + INTERVAL 6 DAY to_interval
FROM symposia s;
```

See the [Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fBR2jcGK6SS1gNR1zhg1h7/3) for dynamic range.

**OLD: If you already know what would be the `start` and `end` day of a week.**

MySQL provides two different functions to retrieve the first day of a week.

> **DAYOFWEEK**: Returns the weekday index for date (1 = Sunday, 2 = Monday, …, 7 = Saturday). These index values correspond to the ODBC standard.
>
> **WEEKDAY**: Returns the weekday index for date (0 = Monday, 1 = Tuesday, … 6 = Sunday).

If you consider `Saturday` as first day and `Friday` as last day(as shown in your output).

```
SELECT 
    s.symposium_date,
    SUBDATE(s.symposium_date, DAYOFWEEK(s.symposium_date)) start_date, -- Monday would be first day
    SUBDATE(s.symposium_date, DAYOFWEEK(s.symposium_date) - 6) end_date -- Add 6 day to find end date, sunday would be last day of week
FROM symposia s;
```

If you consider `Monday` as `the first day of week`:

```
SELECT 
    s.symposium_date,
    SUBDATE(s.symposium_date, WEEKDAY(s.symposium_date)) start_date, -- Monday would be first day
    SUBDATE(s.symposium_date, WEEKDAY(s.symposium_date) - 6) end_date -- Add 6 day to find end date, sunday would be last day of week
FROM symposia s;
```

You can do alternate, to find `Sunday` as first_day and `Saturday` as last.

```
SELECT 
    s.symposium_date,
    SUBDATE(s.symposium_date, WEEKDAY(s.symposium_date) + 1) start_date, -- Sunday would be first day
    SUBDATE(s.symposium_date, WEEKDAY(s.symposium_date) - 5) end_date -- Add 5 day to find end date, Saturday would be last day of week
FROM symposia s;
```

Comment: Output is exactly matching what op has mentioned, it is always first day as `Saturday` and last day as `friday`.

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya, `2019-09-09` date and `2019-09-10` both dates have same interval in expected output.

Comment: @Saswat, can you please verify, is that what you want?

Comment: Check this [fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fBR2jcGK6SS1gNR1zhg1h7/2). As i have provided various option. User is using first one which says `Saturday` as first day and `friday` as last day which uses `dayofweek`.

Comment: I understand `I want a query which will return me the start and end date of each seven day interval tracing backward from NOW()` is confusing with the expected output. Still if you verify whether i am right or not.

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya, you are the experience one here, if you verify its working then i consider it as working. Can you just check once again? I want to say that I have provided option to consider any day as first and last day. Here OP wants the first one where `saturday` as first_day and `friday` as end_day. Waiting for your reply.

Comment: Your approach is good (smart using date functions) for a use-case when the "week" is clearly defined (such as it either starts from Monday, Tuesday or so on..). The problem statement in this case is other way around as the week start date can be dynamic depending on which day the query is actually run. Now, you can try using dynamic values in these functions (`INTERVAL <dynamic depending on current date> DAY`); but I doubt that it accepts integer literals only.

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya, thank you. Yes it works only clear use-cases as you mentioned. And I am not sure about `dynamic value for interval`. Appreciated your response.

Comment: Trying something based on your approach (query); will update you if I can get it to work with dynamic start_date and end_date for a 7 day interval, based on the non-deterministic `CURRENT_DATE()` value.

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya So, you get it now?

Comment: @Strawberry, can you please check my answer for dynamic range.

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya, can you please check my answer for dynamic range.

Comment: @Strawberry, can you verify that issue in this [fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fBR2jcGK6SS1gNR1zhg1h7/6). It seems to give right dates when date is set to `dayofweek('2019-09-10')` which is `3`.

Answer (score 1):

Just to supplement Jtrendra's answer, consider the following - it may not be 100% correct, but hopefully it demonstrates a principle of determining dates relative to other dates.

Let's say that today is a Friday (actually Friday 13th, 2019), and so we want to know on what date Friday occurred in, say, the first week of January. This is equivalent to the `to_interval` value in the OP's example.

I'm using @variables for this example, but you can easily substitute CURDATE() or some other dynamic value...

```
SET @target_date = '2019-01-01';
SET @current_date = '2019-09-13';

SELECT STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT_WS(' '
                            , YEAR(@target_date)
                            , WEEK(@target_date,WEEKDAY(@current_date)) -- WEEKDAY might need tweaking
                            , DATE_FORMAT(@current_date,'%a')
                            ),'%Y %u %a') x;
+------------+
| x          |
+------------+
| 2019-01-04 |
+------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

My previous [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57918400/2469308) is generally suited for the cases when you need **all** the intervals (irrespective of a date lying in those intervals or not). However, in this particular case of yours, as (thankfully) pointed out by *@Strawberry*, you don't really need dynamic number of intervals. So, taking hints from answers by *@Jitendra*, we can employ some mathematics to get the dynamic ranges.

**Logic:** [`WeekDay()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_weekday) function returns the weekday **index** for a given date (0 = Monday, 1 = Tuesday ..). In you case, boundaries of a "week (7-day interval)" are defined based on the **day** of `Current_Date`.

So, if the `Current_Date` is Friday, we need to determine how many days we need to shift from a `symposium_date` to get **weekday index** corresponding to the next Friday (basically `WeekDay(Current_Date)` value). This shift will be simply `WeekDay(Current_Date) - WeekDay(symposium_date)` and will give us `to_interval` date.

Now, getting `from_interval` date is easy; simply subtract 6 days (since we have 7-day interval) from the expression corresponding to `to_interval` date.

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
CREATE TABLE symposia
    (`id` int, `symposium_date` date, `topic` varchar(5), `price` decimal(11,2))
;

INSERT INTO symposia
    (`id`, `symposium_date`, `topic`, `price`)
VALUES
    (1, '2019-09-10', 'Piano', 30.00),
    (2, '2019-09-09', 'Flute', 20.00),
    (3, '2019-09-02', 'Piano', 30.00),
    (4, '2019-08-26', 'Flute', 20.00),
    (5, '2019-08-27', 'Flute', 20.00)
;
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT 
  id, 
  symposium_date, 
  symposium_date + INTERVAL (WEEKDAY(CURRENT_DATE) - WEEKDAY(symposium_date) - 6) DAY AS from_interval, 
  symposium_date + INTERVAL (WEEKDAY(CURRENT_DATE) - WEEKDAY(symposium_date)) DAY AS to_interval
FROM symposia;

| id  | symposium_date | from_interval | to_interval |
| --- | -------------- | ------------- | ----------- |
| 1   | 2019-09-10     | 2019-09-07    | 2019-09-13  |
| 2   | 2019-09-09     | 2019-09-07    | 2019-09-13  |
| 3   | 2019-09-02     | 2019-08-31    | 2019-09-06  |
| 4   | 2019-08-26     | 2019-08-24    | 2019-08-30  |
| 5   | 2019-08-27     | 2019-08-24    | 2019-08-30  |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fBR2jcGK6SS1gNR1zhg1h7/5)